# Telling if two matrices are similar just by observing them

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Tell if these matrices are similar, without any calculations. It's a true/false question, so I am supposed if they are similar, then explain why. I know some rules of matrix similarity, but I am not sure if anything can be concluded just by observation. Thanks

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
0 && 1 && 1 \\
1 && 0 && 1 \\
1 && 1 && 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B= \begin{bmatrix}
2 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && -1 && 1 \\
0 && 0 && -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I can see that they both have one eigenvalue $2$, but I don't know how to see its multiplicities, or if it's enough to conclude if their similarity.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric, $B$ is not

Comment: Is it enough to say that they are not similar? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: All real symmetric matrices are diagonalisable, so $A$ is diagonalisable. You can see that $B$ is not, since the lower right $2 \times 2$ block is not.

Comment: @Joppy okay so is that enough to say they are not similar? based on the fact they are not both diagonalisable?

Comment: @ivana14 yes, since a matrix is diagonalisable iff it is similar to a diagonal matrix. Similarity is transitive: if $A$ is similar to $B$, and $B$ is similar to $C$, then $A$ is similar to $C$, and this is enough to argue that they cannot be similar.

Comment: @Joppy how do you see that the lower right $2 x 2$ block is not diagonalisable just by observing it?